# R parse HTML document and use xpath to get all matches of two patterns

Tags: html, r, xpath

So, I parsed HTML code from FIFA worldcup website, and want to get all the matches:

```
 wcup <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/", useInternalNodes=T)
```

However, the field for one country is 't-nText kern' and for the rest of countries is 't-nText '.

```
 <span class="t-nText kern">Bosnia and Herzegovina</span>
```

Therefore, if I use this command, I will miss 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', like this command:

```
xpathSApply(wcup, "//span[@class='t-nText ']", xmlValue)
```

So, is there any way that I can search for both attributes 't-nText ' and 't-nText kern' at the same time? Or do you have any other solution? I want to keep the order of the matches as is.

xpath doesn't support logical OR:

```
xpathSApply(wcup, "//span[@class='t-nText ' || 't-nText kern']", xmlValue)
XPath error : Invalid expression
//span[@class='t-nText ' || 't-nText kern']
                          ^
XPath error : Invalid expression
//span[@class='t-nText ' || 't-nText kern']
                                          ^
Error in xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, path, fun, ..., namespaces = namespaces,  : 
  error evaluating xpath expression //span[@class='t-nText ' || 't-nText kern']
```

Comment: If all you really need is the matches data, [this site](http://www.excely.com/football/2014-fifa-world-cup-schedule.shtml#.UyV97_l_uSo) has an Excel file all ready to go with the matches (no XML parsing required :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'or' or perhaps 'starts-with()',

```
wcup["//span[@class='t-nText kern' or @class='t-nText ']"]
wcup["//span[starts-with(@class, 't-nText ')]"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I originally posted this ,, then noticed order was needed, so I searched SO for "XPath OR"

Why not just append the results of the two searches together:

```
c( xpathSApply(wcup, "//span[@class='t-nText kern']", xmlValue), 
   xpathSApply(wcup, "//span[@class='t-nText ']", xmlValue)
  )
```

Lo and behold I came up with:

```
xpathSApply(wcup, "//*[starts-with(@class,'t-nText')]", xmlValue)
```

Which appears mighty similar to Martin Morgan's solution. I had not realized that XPath was it's own language. Guess I'm at least 10 years behind the times.